# Found Nil When Unwrapping Optional Value, I keep getting this

Tags: swift, xcode

im having this problem: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

is there any way to solve it?

this is my code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()



           ref.child("ChildA").child("Title").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { DataSnapshot in

               print(DataSnapshot)     // replace this with textLabel or other item
               let m = DataSnapshot.value as? String
               self.TitleA.text = m //Error in this line
           })
```

Comment: Did you check [What does “Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/1187415) Did you read *all of it?* Could it be that `TitleA` is not properly connected in the Storyboard?

Comment: @sasquatch it works on other viewControllers tho

Comment: As pointed out by @MartinR, `TitleA` is probably nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
self.TitleA.text = m
```

With this:

```
self.TitleA?.text = m ?? ""
```

Comment: Its still the same error, thanks for the answer tho

Comment: Check now, your TitleA could be issue.

Comment: Uhh, im having trouble, the code works but the label doesn't change

Comment: Sorry but this is the wrong solution for the problem. If `self.TitleA` is nil then this must be fixed in the Storyboard. Your solution avoids the crash, but does not make the label work.